# Ionic framework real time chat error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, chat

I am trying to make a real time chat in ionic in which the messages are logged in firebase but I'm receiving this error:

```
Error: $scope.chats.$add is not a function
```

The code it suppose to separate the messages by groups and when a message is sent it will send my chats to the firebase using $add 
And here is my code:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ["ionic",'firebase'])

.controller('ChatsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$firebaseArray', '$rootScope', '$ionicHistory', '$state',
  function($scope, $stateParams, $firebaseArray, $rootScope, $ionicHistory, $state) {
           $rootScope.notifyIonicGoingBack = function() {
               $state.go('groups');
            }
            $scope.$myBack = function() {
                $ionicHistory.goBack();
                $rootScope.notifyIonicGoingBack();
              };
            console.log('state ' + $stateParams);
            var ref = new Firebase('https://projectxu.firebaseio.com/chats') //USE OUR Firebase FOR CHAT!!
            $scope.sender_id = 1;
            $scope.group_id = $stateParams.group_id;

            var sync = $firebaseArray(ref);
            sync.$loaded(function (data) {
                var filtered_chats = new Array();
                angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                  if(value.group_id == $scope.group_id) {
                    filtered_chats.push(value);

                 }
                });
                $scope.chats = filtered_chats;
            });




            $scope.sendChat = function(chat){
                console.log("MESSAGE SENT");

              //if($rootScope.authData){
              /*  $scope.chats.$add({
                  user: $rootScope.authData.facebook.username, //SWITCH TO FACEBOOK!!!
                  message: chat.message,
                  imgURL: $rootScope.authData.facebook.cachedUserProfile.profile_img_url
                });
              */

              $scope.chats.$add({
                  sender_id: $scope.sender_id, //SWITCH TO FACEBOOK!!!
                  message: chat.message, 
                  group_id: $scope.group_id, 
                  timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
                  //sender_name: $rootScope.authData.facebook.cachedUserProfile.displayName,
                  //imgURL: $rootScope.authData.facebook.cachedUserProfile.profile_img_url
                });
                chat.message ="";
              console.log("MESSAGE");

            }





}])
```

Comment: Perhaps $scope.chats is not instantiated by the time you call $scope.chats.$add, because it's assigned inside the asynchronous callback of sync.loaded, which may not have finished yet. You need to hook the $add into the result of the loaded? (I don't know ionic specifically)

Comment: I tried moving the $add into the  loaded but still no luck. when i removed   `var filtered_chats = new Array();
                angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                  if(value.group_id == $scope.group_id) {
                    filtered_chats.push(value);

                 }
                });` and replaced  `$scope.chats = filtered_chats;` with `$scope.chats =data;` my chats send to the firebase but they are not separated by group